# Building up a connection between the Turtlebot3 and Remote PC

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

i am just trying to configure my turtlebot3 to learn how to control it etc. Right now I tried to fix the missing connection between the turtlebot3 and my laptop. I did the Instructions from the Turtlebot3 website and set IP addresses for the Remote PC and the Turtlebot3. Both are running under the same wifi. I just ran roscore on my Remote PC and "roslaunch turtlebot3_bringup turtlebot3_robot.launch" on my turtlebot with the follwing results (roscore looks good):

Remote PC:

```
marcel@marcel-macbookpro:~$ roscore
... logging to /home/marcel/.ros/log/e71bc2f6-8857-11e9-bc78-6003088fd8da/roslaunch-marcel-macbookpro-2513.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.
started roslaunch server http://172.11.111.70:42897/
ros_comm version 1.12.14

SUMMARY
========
PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.14
NODES
auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [2524]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://172.11.111.70:11311/
setting /run_id to e71bc2f6-8857-11e9-bc78-6003088fd8da
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [2537]
started core service [/rosout]
```

Turtlebot3:

```
marcel@marcel-desktop:~$ roslaunch turtlebot3_bringup turtlebot3_robot.launch
... logging to /home/marcel/.ros/log/f461929a-8859-11e9-8545-b827eba01879/roslaunch-marcel-desktop-3220.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://172.11.111.112:41073/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.14
 * /turtlebot3_core/baud: 115200
 * /turtlebot3_core/port: /dev/ttyACM0
 * /turtlebot3_core/tf_prefix: 
 * /turtlebot3_lds/frame_id: base_scan
 * /turtlebot3_lds/port: /dev/ttyUSB0

NODES
  /
    turtlebot3_core (rosserial_python/serial_node.py)
    turtlebot3_diagnostics (turtlebot3_bringup/turtlebot3_diagnostics)
    turtlebot3_lds (hls_lfcd_lds_driver/hlds_laser_publisher)

**ERROR: unable to contact ROS master at [http://172.11.111.70:11311]**
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

I then tried to do the network setup with ssh and ping. Basically, I can ping the machines for  itself but not between each other. For the ssh, I get the following error for both, Turtlebot3 and RemotePC:

```
marcel@marcel-desktop:~$ ssh 172.11.111.112
ssh: connect to host 172.11.111.112 port 22: Connection refused
```

Would be great if somebody has a solution for that problem.

Kindly,
Marcel

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324858/building-up-a-connection-between-the-turtlebot3-and-remote-pc/) by [Tima1995](https://answers.ros.org/users/42102/tima1995/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2019-06-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2019-06-07**:
Do you have control over the WiFi setup? Sounds like a firewall may be issue. My Wifi router has a public and private interface. Devices on the public network are not allowed to communicate with each other. Only internet access. On the private network, communication is allowed between devices. Maybe something similar.  Anyway, it isn't a ROS issue if you can't even ping.

Does each computer have internet access? At least that way you're sure they're both really connected to WiFi.

**Comment by [Tima1995](https://answers.ros.org/users/42102/tima1995/) on 2019-06-07**:
Hey billy,
both devices have wifi access and i can ping each device for itself (if I just ping the address of the device).
The wifi network is a public university network, so I dont have a access to the settings.
I tried to fix the ssh thing first, but without access.
What I thought about what might work is, that I can connect my Remote PC by Ethernet Cable and let it act as a wifi router (I own a MacBook). I will try that before I go deeper to the actual network.

**Comment by [Tima1995](https://answers.ros.org/users/42102/tima1995/) on 2019-06-08**:
Okay. Your hint was right. It really was a network issue due to a private/ public network.

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2019-06-08**:
OK, I'll convert my comment to answer. Then you can mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you have control over the WiFi setup? Sounds like a firewall may be issue. My Wifi router has a public and private interface. Devices on the public network are not allowed to communicate with each other. Only internet access. On the private network, communication is allowed between devices. Maybe something similar. Anyway, it isn't a ROS issue if you can't even ping.

Does each computer have internet access? At least that way you're sure they're both really connected to WiFi.

---

Originally posted by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) with karma: 1850 on 2019-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1